# How can I use a new font style (like AR Destiny) in Ionic 2 using Angular 2?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I am working on the Angular 2 with ionic 2 framework. I want to use the AR Destiny font style for my header title. How can I use this font style for the header.

I have downloaded the ARDESTINE.ttf file and placed in src/assets/fonts folder.

in variable.scss i have placed the code

```
$font-path: "../assets/fonts";
```

in app.scss I have placed:

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: "ARDESTINE";
    src: url("/assets/fonts/ARDESTINE.ttf") format("ttf");
 }
```

in my home.scss i have written:

```
.toolbar-title{
    font-family : "ARDESTINE";
}
```

But I am not getting the font as expected...

Comment: Not sure, but aren't you missing two dots ".." before the "assets": `src: url("../assets/fonts/ARDESTINE.ttf") format("ttf");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong path in **app.scss**.

Try:

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: "ARDESTINE";
    src: url("../assets/fonts/ARDESTINE.ttf") format("ttf");
 }
```